# Correct image after compare two json arrays sometimes not display

Tags: arrays, json, swift, compare

I have 2 Json arrays which I try to compare in my code -> all and allUrl.
When array all contains some id from array allUrl image table row should be change to red, or vice versa green.
But sometimes is working and red image in table row displayed correct but sometimes not.

There is my code for this part:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

cell.textLabel?.text = all[indexPath.row].id
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = all[indexPath.row].timestampValue

let listOfStudentsUrl = allUrl.reduce(into: [String:String]()){$0[$1.id] =  $1.timestampValue}
           // Compare data

        listOfStudentsUrl.forEach{ key in print(key)    

        if  cell.textLabel?.text == key.key {
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"red_icon")
        }else{
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"green_icon")
    }}
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `break`. Once you find `key` is available, you need to set the image and exit. Here, what happens is you set the image and then you check again. In effect, your image depends on the last element of the array.

```
if  cell.textLabel?.text == key.key {
    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"red_icon")
    break
} else {
    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"green_icon")
}
```

Comment: Good point thanks but I get this:
Unlabeled 'break' is only allowed inside a loop or switch, a labeled break is required to exit an if or do

Comment: You would have to change from `forEach` closure to `for in` loop here.

Comment: Do you mean this?Because image dissapeared.
for key in listOfStudentsUrl{
            // Compare data
        
            if  cell.textLabel?.text == key.key {
            
           cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"red_icon")
            break
        } else {
            cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"green_icon")
            }}

Comment: do debug each iteration using a breakpoint or a print statement and watch what is happening.

Comment: Yes It's working, thank you @Frankenstein!!!
 I found it, my mistake with name for icons.

Comment: Correct code :
        for key in listOfStudentsUrl{
            // Compare data
        
            if  cell.textLabel?.text == key.key {
            
           cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"red_icon")
            break
        } else {
            cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"green_icon")
            }}
        return cell
    }

Comment: Try using image literal instead of the old uiimage named syntax. This would avoid such mistakes.